# How do I add a zsh plugin with prezto?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Im not very familiar with the whole zsh ecosystem and there is some stuff that has confused me.

Im using prezto (I know I dont *need* a framework) which has mostly all the things I need out of the box but I also want this: https://github.com/esc/conda-zsh-completion

How do I install plugins with prezto? Prezto has its own "modules" and there does not appear to be one for conda autocompletion. How to I install this plugin?

Does prezto not support installing zsh plugins and I have to install it manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Inside Prezto's base dir, create a dir called `contrib`.
2. Inside this `contrib` dir, `git clone` the `conda-zsh-completion` plugin.
3. In your `~/.zpreztorc` file, add `conda-zsh-completion` to `zstyle ':prezto:load' pmodule`.
4. Restart your terminal.

To update the plugin, `cd` into its dir and do `git pull`.

Documentation on using external plugins with Prezto can be found here: https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto#external-modules

Comment: dear lord why could I not find this information? The documentation with this plugin itself doesnt explain how to do this either. I installed a plugin manager (zinit) thinking prezto could not do this

Comment: The preferred place to put your customizations is not in `modules/`, but in `contrib/`. New modules could be added that conflict with your customizations if you don't use contrib. You are correct - the docs aren't super clear about this.

Comment: @mattmc3 Thanks for the tip! I updated my answer.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling around to get `conda-zsh-completion` to work, you have to follow this answer and add the following lines to your `.zshrc` file *after* the `conda initialize` code: https://github.com/conda-incubator/conda-zsh-completion/blob/306e16f57356e352a5244ad6fbe9bc26b6247358/_conda#L31-L32